# Wordpress navigation at postspage

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am working on a site as an intern.
The site is called www.erikzandstra.nl (its dutch)
Currently, I am working on the blog page.
On the blog page, I wanted to add some php code to get navigation buttons to go to the next and previous posts.
I searched through internet and could not find any code that worked.(i'm not a php programmer)
Here is the code I currently use:

```
<?php get_header( $name ); ?>
        <div id="content" class="clearfix row">

            <div id="main" class="col-sm-8 clearfix" role="main">

                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clearfix'); ?> role="article">

                    <header>

                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'wpbs-featured' ); ?></a>

                        <div class="page-header"><h1 class="h2"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1></div>

                        <p class="meta"><?php _e("Posted", "wpbootstrap"); ?> <time datetime="<?php echo the_time('Y-m-j'); ?>" pubdate><?php echo get_the_date('F jS, Y', '','', FALSE); ?></time> <?php _e("by", "wpbootstrap"); ?> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> <span class="amp">&</span> <?php _e("filed under", "wpbootstrap"); ?> <?php the_category(', '); ?>.</p>

                    </header> <!-- end article header -->

                    <section class="post_content clearfix">
                        <?php the_content( __("Read more &raquo;","wpbootstrap") ); ?>
                    </section> <!-- end article section -->

                    <footer>

                        <p class="tags"><?php the_tags('<span class="tags-title">' . __("Tags","wpbootstrap") . ':</span> ', ' ', ''); ?></p>

                    </footer> <!-- end article footer -->

                </article> <!-- end article -->

                <?php endwhile; ?>  

                <?php if (function_exists('wp_bootstrap_page_navi')) { // if expirimental feature is active ?>

                <?php wp_bootstrap_page_navi(); // use the page navi function ?>

                <?php } else { // if it is disabled, display regular wp prev & next links ?>
                    <nav class="wp-prev-next">
                        <ul class="pager">
```

```
                <?php else : ?>

                <article id="post-not-found">
                    <header>
                        <h1><?php _e("Not Found", "wpbootstrap"); ?></h1>
                    </header>
                    <section class="post_content">
                        <p><?php _e("Sorry, but the requested resource was not found on this site.", "wpbootstrap"); ?></p>
                    </section>
                    <footer>
                    </footer>
                </article>

                <?php endif; ?>

            </div> <!-- end #main -->

            <?php get_sidebar(); // sidebar 1 ?>

        </div> <!-- end #content -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

If you have answers, or can point me to a tutorial, that would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `wp_bootstrap_page_navi()` seems to be the function for displaying page navigation on your page. Please check if you have code in this function or not. Also your blog page is not showing all blog posts right now I guess.

Answer (score 0):

For next post link use:

```
<?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next post >'); ?>
```

For prev post link use:

```
<?php previous_posts_link('%link', '< Prev post'); ?>
```

For more info read https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link

Comment: I used the code but when i refreshed the page it didnt show any link to another post

Comment: @Naaman and you sure there is older or newer post? Where you post it? There is any error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using "paged" parameter when querying the post/post_type data.

Here is an example.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=3&paged=' . $paged );
```

[Read documentation to get better understanding](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination)

Also, ask WordPress related questions [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)